# How to keep GUI running smoothly with multiple levels of sub threads

Tags: qt

QT 5.15.2, MSVC, Win10 x64

I'm trying to call a subthread from within a subthread while still having the main GUI run properly.

The GUI calls the "open file" function which launches the outer subthread from the `QThreadPool` and returns immediately to avoid GUI lockup.  The `QThreadPool` thread launches the inner thread, moves the new worker object to the inner thread, triggers a slow init procedure in the inner object, then *when that procedure is done*, causes a main-thread GUI object to start up a new window.  The `QThreadPool` thread then quits.

The innermost thread is a long running thread, the primary purpose of which is to hold an object which maintains access to the `QSqlDatabase`.  For now when it initializes it fills the db with dummy values, deliberately intended to take a long time.  I had to do this because Qt requires that the thread which opens the db also closes the db, and `QThreadPool` doesn't appear to have any mechanism to request a specific thread, i.e., "give me the specific thread I used to open the db a while ago".  So I create a new thread and keep it running until its sole object causes it to quit a long time later.

The problem is I can't find the correct invocation of `Qt::QueuedConnection` , `Qt::Blocking QueuedConnection`, etc., to use which properly launches the init sequence in the background without locking up the GUI.  When I use `Qt::QueuedConnection`, I think the second call is launched before the first call is finished.  When I use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`, it locks up the GUI (and a test indicates the slow procedure is running on the main thread in this case), and anyway the Qt documentation says the `BlockingQueuedConnection` is to be used when returning a value, which I'm not doing.  I want the calls within the `doOpen` lambda below to run in sequence, while the whole thing is concurrent with the main thread.

```
template<typename T>
inline void newDoc(std::string userType, Emdi & emdi, docVec_t & docVec) {
    // Typically newDoc runs in the main thread as is it called from the menu
    // and returns quickly.
    // The doOpen is run in another thread as it may take a long time
    std::string docname = docName<T>();
    auto doOpen = [&emdi, docname, userType, &docVec]{
        auto dtw = new DocThreadWrapper(std::make_unique<T>(docname));
        auto thr = new QThread;
        dtw->moveToThread(thr);
        thr->start();

        qDebug() << "starting open";
        T *doc = static_cast<T *>(dtw->get());

        // This should run on the newly created sub-subthread
        // This takes a few seconds to run and locks up the GUI
        // when using BlockingQueuedConnection
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&emdi, "openDocument",
                                  Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                                  Q_ARG(IDocument *, doc));

        // THEN, this should run on the main GUI thread
        // Opening the new MDI Frame is fast
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&emdi, "newMdiFrame",
                                  Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                                  Q_ARG(std::string, docname),
                                  Q_ARG(std::string, userType));

        // THEN this should print
        qDebug() << "opened";

    };
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(doOpen);
}
```

Comment: If `openDocument` must complete *before* `newMdiFrame` starts then why not just have a single function `openDocumentAndCreateNewMdiFrame` (for example) that calls them in sequence.  Then just call `openDocumentAndCreateNewMdiFrame` using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` connection type?  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: This is correct, but I think just pushes the problem deeper into the code.  The `BlockingQueuedConnection` indicated it was running on the main thread.  I'll keep trying.

Comment: Now I'm seing the queued connection appears to be corrupting the Q_ARG arguments in the receiving `newMdiFrame`, even though it's correctly running `newMdiFrame` in the main thread.  Weird.

Comment: I had was using `qRegisterMetaType` incorrectly and this was causing weird data in the called function.